# How to work with a script in qpython without leaving

Tags: python, qpython

I'm trying to run a script, `QTS.v0.2.1.py`, in `qpython`, but when I run it, it will not let me work with the functions and variables I have written since I intend to use the interpreter. I pulse to execute the script and before the cursor appears the following line:

[QPython] Press enter to exit

That way I can not work because I press enter and exit. I can not introduce anything. Before this there is the following code:

```
/data/use/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh 
"/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/QTS.v0.v2.1.py" && exit
python.qpy3/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh 
"/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/QTS.v0.2.1.py && exit
```

It seems that what you read in the end, the "&& exit" has something to do, but I do not understand what happens. I've given it to the gearwheel symbol, configuration, and I do not see any option that specifies that when executing a script the following is closed.

How can I work in console mode with the functions and variables of my script?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the script/project to you default import path and than import it.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/storage/emulated/0/qpython/projects')
sys.path.append('/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts ')
```

when you working with qpython 3, change it to scripts3 and projects3

now you can do:

```
import MyScript
```

or:

```
from MyProject import MyClass
```

Comment: ¿How can I import the Script into the Interpreter?

Comment: You can add it via sys.path.append('your scripts path')